# FreeForm Pro {all_form_fields} ordering fields by order in form

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm creating a Notification Template with this tag pair:

```
{all_form_fields}
    {field_label}
    {field_data}
{/all_form_fields}
```

But the order's ending up alphabetical, not in the order I put them in Composer.

After finding http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/15678 then seeing that this appeared to be fixed at http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/change_log/#v4.0.11:

> Fixed a bug where Notification templates using the '{all_form_fields}'
>   variable pair were not ordering data by the field order set in the
>   form edit screen in the CP and were going in Alphabetical order
>   instead.

I'm not sure what to do. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What version of Freeform and EE are you using? Are you using the Freeform _Composer_? That changelog item was for forms using template forms, i.e. `{exp:freeform:form}`.

Comment: Using EE 2.7.3 and FF 4.1.7. Yes, using Composer. Using a Notification Template from a Composer form, is there any way to output the fields in the order they are in Composer? That is, apart from making a new Notification Template for each form with manually-added fields.

Comment: Unfortunately this ordering isn't available for Composer forms. Manually adding fields in a notification template, as you mentioned, is the way to go at this time. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on.
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions

Comment: I've received the same question from one of our clients. Has this been addressed yet? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making so many custom notifications for long forms, I wrote this script to make it easy. You can run this and put the lines in the correct order.

```
<?
$sql = "SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='ee_facs' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='exp_freeform_form_entries_65';";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) {
    $column_name = mysql_result($result, $i, "COLUMN_NAME");
    if (strpos($column_name, "form_field") !== false) {
        // look up form field's label + name
        $field_id = trim($column_name, "form_field_");
        $sql = "SELECT field_name, field_label FROM exp_freeform_fields WHERE field_id = $field_id";
        $field_result = mysql_query($sql);
        $field_name = mysql_result($field_result, 0, "field_name");
        $field_label = mysql_result($field_result, 0, "field_label");
        echo "&lt;p&gt;" . $field_label . ": {" . $field_name . "}&lt;/p&gt; <br>";
    }
} //for
?>
```

This outputs like:

```
<p>First Name: {first_name}</p> 
<p>Last Name: {last_name}</p>
```